# Adding the size of the image that one tries to upload

Tags: feature-request, uploader

How about adding the size of the image that one tries to upload, when it's over MiB?

I sometime try to upload an image which gets refused due to its size, and have no idea how far I am from 2 MiB (i.e. how much resizing I need to do). Saving the image on the disk and checking for its size is a bit tedious.

[image]

Comment: What do you need this information for? If you're going to shrink the image down, you need to download it either way.

Comment: @Emrakul it's a screenshot, if too large then I go to some image editor to resize it, without saving to hard disk.

Comment: Not sure that info is available before the image is actually submitted

Comment: How is this easier than checking the size of the file on the disk that you've dragged into the window after you have done so?

Comment: @ShadowWizard How does the uploader know its above 2 MiB? (just curious, I am also not sure that info is available before the image is actually submitted)

Comment: @MichaelT Well it's one step easier.

Comment: The uploader gets the entire file, stores it to a temporary location, checks the file for various things (its actually a supported image file format, it is within size constraints, etc...) and then, if all the checks are made, moves it into the publicly available lookup. If it fails, it deletes the temporary file. --- and while it may be one step faster, that is one step that you are going to do *somewhere* along the line no matter what. When editing in some image editors, scaling the image will show the current and resulting file size. You will also need to be checking for MiB vs MB.

Comment: @Franck as far as I know, it doesn't. It sends the picture, and if it's too big the server sends an error.

Comment: @Zyerah While it's at it, why can't it just downsize if it's too big, in case I'm on a machine that doesn't have any easy way of editing pictures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really not necessary.  Any competent image editor will tell you what you need to know while resizing.

[image]

If yours doesn't, get a new one.

Comment: But is your competent image editor fast to load? I was sticking to a simple image editor so that it opens immediately.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Faster than you can do the math in your head.

Comment: Great, what's the name?

Comment: This one is paint.net

Comment: How about any competent web site that lets you upload should be automatically able to scale it for you for people who are on a machine why doesn't have any imaging editors available?

Comment: Sounds like a feature request, m8

Answer (score 3):

Frank, I'm a little confused. If the image is too large, you know you have to shrink it. Knowing that it's 3 MB instead of 2 MB won't help you figure out by how many pixels to shrink it.

Instead, simply make it smaller and try again. Rinse and repeat.

The more efficient approach would be to simply save it, and then edit the picture as needed.

Don't get me wrong, I'm not against displaying extra information, I just don't know that it would be particularly useful.

Comment: Actually, knowing that it's 3 MB instead of 2 MB does help me figure out by how many pixels to shrink it.

Comment: @Franck - I think you may be a bit of a special case in that regard. I think 99% of users would not mind saving to the HDD, or shrinking by trial and error. Overall, I think this change would not significantly help too many people.

Comment: Yes, unsure what other people's workflow is. (but I do think saving on disk is a bit inefficient, since it's one unnecessary step if one didn't have to check for the file size). Just trying to propose ways to make Stack Exchange use faster :-)